# Prove these are relatively prime. (involving Greatest Common Divisor)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I know that we have to use prime factorization.

$\gcd(\alpha,\beta)$ => using minimum

$\text{lcm}(\alpha,\beta)$ => using maximum

$$\gcd(\alpha,\beta) \times \text{lcm}(\alpha,\beta) = a * b$$

How do I continue or any tips?

Thank You.

Comment: It's not actually necessary to mention prime factorizations in order to do this.  Prime factorizations are used to find GCDs and LCMs, but that can be difficult when very large numbers are involved.  But GCDs can be found very efficiently by using Euclid's algorithm even when prime factorizations are onerous.  Euclid's algorithm is the oldest algorithm still in standard use---about 23 centuries---and yet it hasn't been improved on very much.  Google the term if you're not familiar with it.  It's worth knowing if you're going to think about things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can give a simple proof using Bezout's Theorem. Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=d$. Thus $da'x+db'y=d$, and therefore $a'x+b'y=1$. Relative primality follows.

**Another way:** (better) Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$. If $k\gt 1$ divides both $a'$ and $b'$, then $kd$ divides both $a$ and $b$, contradicting the fact that $d$ is the *greatest* common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\gcd(a',b') = \gcd\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right) = 1$$